# DataAnnotation client side with jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I found many tutorials how to do custom client side validation with ASP.NET MVC 3 validation ([example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvccustomvalidation_topic2)):

```
Sys.Mvc.ValidatorRegistry.validators["priceOnRange"] = function(rule) {
    var minPrice = rule.ValidationParameters.minPrice;
    var maxPrice = rule.ValidationParameters.maxPrice;
    var message = rule.ErrorMessage;

    return function (value, context) {
        if (value > maxPrice || value < minPrice) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
};
```

this is module for validating price for custom DataAnnotation for PriceRange but how can i convert to jQuery plugin or call this with jQuery without referencing scripts from Microsoft.

Comment: What version of asp.net mvc are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC 3, the more modern, unobtrusive style validation is used by default, which uses jQuery validation plugin, not the `MicrosoftMvcValidation`. So, by default, in mvc3, you should not need to reference Microsoft scripts. Take a look at [Brad Wilson's Presentation](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2011/02/advanced-aspnet-mvc-3-presentation.html) about custom unobtrusive validation. He covers number of topics there, including custom validation.